# Remove SKAction and restore node state

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, skaction, sknode

Desired behavior is: when an action is removed from a node (with `removeAction(forKey:)` for instance) it stops to animate and  all the changes caused by action are discarded, so the node returns back to pervious state. In other words, I want to achieve behavior similar to `CAAnimation`.

But when a `SKAction` is removed, the node remains changed. It's not good, because to restore it's state I need to know exactly what action was removed. And if I then change the action, I also will need to update the node state restoration.

Update:
The particular purpose is to show possible move in a match-3 game. When I show a move, pieces start pulsating (`scale` action, repeating forever). And when the user moves I want to stop showing the move, so I remove the action. As the result, pieces may remain downscaled. Later I would like to add more fancy and complicated animations, so I want to be able to edit it easily.

Comment: You do not want to be using SKActions in this regard then.  Look into GameplayKit and its state machine functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comment and answer I came to my own solution. I think the state machine would be bit too heavy here. Instead I created a wrapper node, which main purpose is run the animation. It also has a state: `isAimating` property. But, first of all, it allows to keep `startAnimating()` and `stopAnimating()` methods close to each other, incapsulated, so it's more difficult to mess up.

```
class ShowMoveAnimNode: SKNode {
    let animKey = "showMove"

    var isAnimating: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            guard oldValue != isAnimating else { return }
            if isAnimating {
                startAnimating()
            } else {
                stopAnimating()
            }
        }
    }

    private func startAnimating() {
        let shortPeriod = 0.2
        let scaleDown = SKAction.scale(by: 0.75, duration: shortPeriod)
        let seq = SKAction.sequence([scaleDown,
                                     scaleDown.reversed(),
                                     scaleDown,
                                     scaleDown.reversed(),
                                     SKAction.wait(forDuration: shortPeriod * 6)])
        let repeated = SKAction.repeatForever(seq)
        run(repeated, withKey: animKey)
    }

    private func stopAnimating() {
        removeAction(forKey: animKey)
        xScale = 1
        yScale = 1
    }
}
```

Usage: just add everything that should be animated to this node. Works well with simple animations, like: fade, scale and move.

Answer (score 1):

As @Knight0fDragon suggested, you would be better off using the `GKStateMachine` functionality, I will give you an example.

First declare the states of your player/character in your scene

```
lazy var playerState: GKStateMachine = GKStateMachine(states: [
    Idle(scene: self),
    Run(scene: self)
    ])
```

Then you need to create a class for each of these states, in this example I will show you only the `Idle` class

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class Idle: GKState {
   weak var scene: GameScene?

    init(scene: SKScene) {
        self.scene = scene as? GameScene
        super.init()
    }

    override func didEnter(from previousState: GKState?) {
        //Here you can make changes to your character when it enters this state, for example, change his texture.
    }

    override func isValidNextState(_ stateClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
        return stateClass is Run.Type //This is pretty obvious by the method name, which states can the character go to from this state.
    }

    override func update(deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval) {
        //Here is the update method for this state, lets say you have a button which controls your character velocity, then you can check if the player go over a certain velocity you make it go to the Run state.

       if playerVelocity > 500 { //playerVelocity is just an example of a variable to check the player velocity.
          scene?.playerState.enter(Run.self)
       }
    }
}
```

Now of course in your scene you need to do two things, first is initialize the character to a certain state or else it will remain stateless, so you can to this in the `didMove` method.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    playerState.enter(Idle.self)
}
```

And last but no least is make sure the scene update method calls the state update method.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    playerState.update(deltaTime: currentTime)
}
```